# Why is my series EE bond's next accrual date not a multiple of 6 months after the issue date

Tags: bonds, government-bonds

My grandparents gave me a few Series EE bonds while I was growing up.  I have entered their serial numbers/issue dates into [this calculator on treasurydirect.gov](https://www.treasurydirect.gov/BC/SBCPrice).

Most of the bonds' issue date was in April (as early as late 1995).

The calculator is reporting the next accrual date is in June (2 months later). 
 **Why would this be?**

---

**Examples**

```
+------------+--------------+
| Issue Date | Next Accrual |
+------------+--------------+
| 12/1995    | 06/2020*     |
| 04/1999    | 06/2020      |
| 04/2001    | 06/2020      |
| 12/2003    | 06/2020*     |
| 03/2005    | 06/2020      |
| 05/2008    | 06/2020      |
| 04/2009    | 06/2020      |
| 04/2011    | 06/2020      |
+------------+--------------+
```

* means this makes sense to me

(table made using [Senseful Solutions](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/))

---

**Background Research**

[When Interest is Added to Your Bonds](https://www.treasurydirect.gov/indiv/research/indepth/ebonds/res_e_bonds_eeratesandterms_increaseinvalue.htm) doesn't mention any other accrual date besides some multiple of 6 months after the issue date's month.

Comment: It will help if you can give the month/year they were issued... looking at your second link, some bonds have interest paid monthly (in which case, in the middle of May, one would expect the next accrual to be in June). Also, "_Interest is added monthly the first five years for EE Bonds issued March 1993 through April 1995 and semiannually after that, **unless monthly additions are needed to make sure the bonds earn at least 4%**_" may apply, so it's conceivable that June could be a top-up month.

Comment: Thank you @TripeHound for answering!  I should say, I started receiving bonds in late 1995, so the asterisk statement you mention (`EE Bonds issued March 1993 through April 1995...`) wouldn't apply.  Good thinking though.  I have added a bunch of example issue date + next accrual date pairings to the question.  Do you need any other information?